# Get matrix from textfile in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

What's the easiest way to turn [this](http://hyperpublic.com/challenge2input.txt) text file into matrix? It has one row per line, where `O` means `0` and `X` means `1`

Comment: What language you using?

Comment: you should treat yourself with a numeric keypad :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I first saved that text in a file tmp.txt.

```
In[180]:= words = ReadList["~danl/tmp.txt", Word];
vals = Map[Characters, words] /. {"O" -> 0, "X" -> 1};

In[182]:= vals[[1]]
Out[182]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Answer (score 10):

```
$url = "http://hyperpublic.com/challenge2input.txt";
StringCases[Import[$url, "Lines"], {"O" -> 0, "X" -> 1}]
```

Comment: Wait, you can use URLs as arguments to `Import`? How cool is that?

Comment: Congrats on your 10k! I had to find an answer that I hadn't already upvoted to bump you over :)